# This build is invalid. for uploading app

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

Hello I am uploading app first time in App Store.

But when i upload app then build not appear and in activity menu its show This build is invalid.

I got mail from apple In this wrote

> Invalid Bundle - There's an issue with the app's bitcode compilation. Rebuild the app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and upload it again.

I have bundle 4 time but none of this happen

Can you give me suggestion how i can do????

Thanks

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Xcode 7.2.1 is the current GM version.

Comment: ok i will updated Xcode and replied it thanks

Comment: you're probably using a gold master version, try to get the stable version from the Mac AppStore, or from the apple website at the following link: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Xcode to
[7.2.1](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12) . Always use latest version of Xcode when you're submitting an app to App Store, otherwise it won't accept it.

Comment: currently use OS X Yosemite

Comment: I don't know, try updating if it requires OS update it will tell you to update your OS before Xcode